# Incremental solution for matrix inverse using Shermann-Morrison in $O(n^2)$

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, linear-algebra, matrix-inverse

I have been reading a presentation on [Value Function Approximation](http://www0.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/d.silver/web/Teaching_files/FA.pdf) by David Silver (Introduction to Reinforcement Learning Course). On page 43 he finds a solution for linear least squares for an unknown parameter vector $w$. He claims that, for $N$ features, inverting a matrix is $O(N^3)$, but an incremental solution using Sherman-Morrison algorithm with complexity of $O(N^2)$ is possible ([see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1boKF.png)). Since [Sherman–Morrison formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula) allows for computing an inverse of the sum of an invertible matrix $A$ and the outer product, $uv^T$, of vectors $u$ and $v$, I don't really see how this applies to this case as well.

Comment: Fun question (+1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Within the context of linear regression, the estimated $\beta$ parameters are given $(X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty$. The main computational burden in this formula is the inversion the matrix $A = X^TX$. In the use-case of batch learning, we have already estimate for $A$ as well as for $A^{-1} = (X^TX)^{-1}$ from our previous iteration. When we get another batch we can look into how this can be expressed as an additive change on $A$ in the form of $A_{new} = A + uv^T$. Notice that the extra sample/batch will extend $X$ by a row but it will leave $A$ to be the same dimensions as before. Thus, we have $A_{new}^{-1}= (A+uv^T)^{-1} = A^{-1} - \frac{A^{-1}uv^TA^{-1}}{1 + v^TA^{-1}u}$.